# GCP deploying flask app results in error 13

Tags: flask, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gunicorn

I am trying to deploy a simple flask application on GCP using gunicorn as WSGI.

Because I'm very new to GCP, I followed [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/quickstart#windows) to lead the way.

When I try to use the command `gcp app deploy` it results in the following error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] The system encountered a fatal error

When looking at the logs I can see the following:
[image: logs gcp]

My app.yaml looks like this:

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 2.5
  disk_size_gb: 64
```

My file structure:

```
.
├── app.yaml
├── main.py
├── requirements.txt
├── static
│   ├── index.js
│   └── style.css
...
```

If there is anything else I need to include, let me know.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do the service run locally? Do you really need Flex instance? not standard?

Comment: Do you mean with "Do the service run locally?" if the app runs locally? If that's the question - yes it does, it works great! And I'm not sure about the app engine environment, I did some [research](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments). And I don't think it doesn't really mind being flex or standard in my case, but I will try and let you know.

Comment: So I tried changing the flex instancer to a standard instance. This resulted in changing the ```runtime: python``` to ```runtime: python38```. But after running the app I got a result saying Flask is running, but still mentioning it isn't using a WSGI server and also it throws an error >Missing 'graphviz' - please run 'conda install fastbook'

Comment: Does your requirements.txt required binary installation or specific runtime environment (os libraries)?

Comment: My requirements.txt contains following libraries:

```
fastai==2.5.3
fastbook==0.0.18
Flask==2.0.2
requests==2.26.0
webdriver_manager==3.5.2
Werkzeug==2.0.1
gunicorn==20.1.0
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question and share your `main.py` file to have a [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?
I've used this [sample with Gunicorn](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04), but couldn't reproduce the error you've got.